# How to disable Toolbar in android activity?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, toolbar

I'm trying disable the toolbar in my Login Activity. I have tried all the methods i could find so far.

```
<application
    android:name="app.AppController"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

here is my styles xml file

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

I have even tried to remove it programatically with

```
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

also removed these lines of codes.

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

still no luck. I dont see the toolbar in my design preview in android studio. But when i run the app using the emulator it shows the toolbar. I'm emulating it on a Nexus 4 with the api 22.

Have i missed anything or done something wrong? Can anyone point me in the right direction.

Comment: Check your `Activity` `XML` and remove `Toolbar` from there, if present.

Comment: oh thanks! silly me. i totally forget about the activity xml since i was working on the content xml so far. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have forgotten to remove the toolbar from the activity xml. I had only removed the toolbar from the content xml file.